# How to upgrade Ubuntu in multiple sessions?

Tags: upgrade

**We can apply updates in multiple sessions**. That is,if I have 10 updates,I can install 4 on one day and remaining 6 on some other day.

**Is the same also possible with upgrade?** So can I download some part of upgrade in first session,later in second and then apply it?

This can be useful when it is impossible,or difficult to download large data(generally more than 750 Mb)
    in a single go(due to speed drops,data limits etc).

Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I want to upgrade to 14.04.

> Many users in Asia and Africa rely on connections with  limited data,
>   which are slow and discontinuous.Ability to upgrade in multiple
>   session can be of great help to all such users.

Comment: You can not directly upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04, you would need to make a clean install.

Comment: I am ready to upgrade as 12.10>13.04>13.10>14.04.The main point is that I can't download large data continuously.So I need to upgrade in sessions.

Comment: it's easier and uses less data to just install Ubuntu 14.04, instead of doing the upgrades. But 14.04 is not yet released...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most advisable in your case is simply downloading the ISO image and do an in-place upgrade instead of going thru the whole upgrade path. This way you can control how much data you use per day and upgrade at any time.

Remember to do backups.